# How to get the master layout slide name

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm populating PowerPoint slides with data from an Excel spread sheet. At the moment, I'm accessing the slide using the page number:

```
Set mySlide = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
```

Using the Master View option in the UI, you can rename the slide. How can I find the slide using that name?

Thanks,

Carlo.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do ... find a SLIDE with a certain name or a LAYOUT with a certain name, or find the name of the LAYOUT the current slide's based on.  ActivePresentation.Slides("Carlo") will return a reference to the slide named "Carlo" ... if there is one.

Comment: I want to be able to give each slide a unique name (through the PPT UI) and then be able to find the slide using that name using a script that is run in Excel. There is a UniqueID parameter for each slide, but if we copy a slide from one presentation to another, I need to still be able to identify slide "XYZ" as the same thing but I doubt the UniqueID value would move with the slide.

Answer (score 2):

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Master.Design.Name
```

It is the name you see for the theme, in the master view for the slide.

```
layoutIndex = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).CustomLayout.Index
```

It is the current layout of the slide in the above theme.

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Master.Design.Parent.CustomLayouts.Item(layoutIndex).Name
```

It is the layout name of the currently selected layout of the slide.

it is the VBA, what you can say :-).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Slide.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744041%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property will define the name of the slide and allow it to be called using:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides("Name")
```

[per the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746073%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: But, how do I set the Slide.Name property through the UI?  I have a PPT presentation that I'm using as a template. I need to set the Name property for each of the existing pages as well as for any new pages that are added.

Comment: You can only access the slide name via code; if you need to expose it to the user, you'll have to provide the UI.  If the need is simply to create globally unique IDs for each slide (as opposed to unique to a given presentation IDs) perhaps code that generates and assigns GUIDs as the slide's name would work.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I wanted was a way to uniquely identify a PPT slide through VBA. The problem is that I still need to be able to identify that slide if it is copied to another PPT document.

So, what I found I had to do was:

- create a text box on each page and hard-code the text to be something like "Slide:Cover" or "Slide:QuarterlyResults", etc.
- loop through each slide
- find "Slide:" and strip it out to get the page title. That way, if the slide is copied to another PPT document, the name goes with it.
- create a Dictionary that uses the Slide.SlideID as the key and the page title as the value.

Then what I do is loop through the slides, get the SlideID, use the Dictionary to get the page title and use a Select statement to map to the proper method to process the slide.

Yeah, I know... it's an icky hack, but it's the only way I could think of doing it.

Thanks for you help,

Carlo.

Comment: Supplying all the details of the question in the first place would have saved you some time, and maybe this can save you some work:  look up .Tags Each slide can have as many tags (name/value pairs) as you like; no need to reinvent the wheel you're proposing above. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Steve. When I first started this, I thought the layout would give me what I needed. I'm a PowerPoint newbie. As I got deeper into it, I realized it wouldn't.

I looked up .Tags but didn't see how I could "tag" a slide through the UI. (Am I missing something?) I need the person generating the slide to be able to give it a unique name that I can then access through code.